# why is it consoling an empty array?

Tags: javascript, regex, file-handling, map-function

```
const testFolder = '../assets';
const fs = require('fs');

const array=[]
const pattern=/gif/
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.map(file => {
    if(file.search(pattern)>0)
        array.push(file)
  });
// console.log(files)
});
console.log(array)
```

It should be printing an array of all the files containing .gif extension .But it is printing an empty array .Not sure why the heck this is happening ...

Comment: `fs.readdir` is asynchronous ... `console.log(array)` is executed before anything inside `(err, files) => { ..... }` runs

Comment: @Raxel21 - let that be our little secret :p - to be honest, you were correct though ... because `gif.txt` is not a gif :p

Answer (score 1):

The console.log(array) call will happen *before* the array is actually populated, since the callback will take a little time to be called.

If you place the log statement within the callback, you'll get the list of files as expected.

I'd also suggest using [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this case.

```
const testFolder = '../assets';
const fs = require('fs');

const pattern = /\.gif$/i
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    const array = files.filter(file => pattern.test(file))
    console.log(array)
});
```

You could also use [`fs.readdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) if you wish to use a synchronous version of readdir.

```
const testFolder = '../assets';
const fs = require('fs');

const pattern = /\.gif$/i
const allFiles = fs.readdirSync(testFolder)
const gifFiles = allFiles.filter(file => pattern.test(file))
console.log(gifFiles)
```

Comment: I would suggest using `regexp.test` ... `pattern.test(file)` since you just need the truthiness of the match ... I'd also suggest the pattern needs to be `/\.gif$/i` ... but that's just me being pedantic :p

Comment: Good points @JaromandaX, I think programmers are allowed to be pedantic :-).. I think that's a better answer.

Comment: pedantry is a pre-requisite for being a programmer :p